# How is data disk consumed iops percentage calculated for a VM in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a VM with only one data disk. The disk is of StandardSSD. 128GB.

At a certain point,

```
Max data disk IOPS consumed percentage = 100%. 
Max Data Disk Used Burst IO Credits Percentage = 30% 
Avg Disk Write Operations/sec(Preview) = 542/s 
Avg Disk Read Operations/sec(Preview) = 540
```

Isn't Consumed IOPS = (Read + Write)/Provisioned ? If not how is it calculated in azure ?

Comment: The Data Disk IOPS Consumed Percentage is calculated by dividing the actual data disk IOPS completed by the provisioned data disk IOPS. If the percentage is at 100%, then the application running is IO capped from the data disk's IOPS limit. The formula you mentioned, Consumed IOPS = (Read + Write)/Provisioned, is not the correct formula for calculating the Data Disk IOPS Consumed Percentage in Azure.

Comment: In your case, if the Max data disk IOPS consumed percentage is 100%, it means that your application is IO capped from the data disk's IOPS limit. The Max Data Disk Used Burst IO Credits Percentage of 30% means that you have used 30% of the burst credits that are available to your disk. The Avg Disk Write Operations/sec and Avg Disk Read Operations/sec are not used in the calculation of the Data Disk IOPS Consumed Percentage.

Comment: References:
-   [Disk performance metrics - Storage IO utilization metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-metrics#storage-io-utilization-metrics)

Comment: @Arko Is the method used by Azure to calculate the consumed IOPS percentage documented anywhere in their official documentation?

Comment: the specific formula Azure uses to calculate the `Consumed IOPS Percentage` at a given moment might not be explicitly detailed in their public documentation. The doc does explain the provisioned IOPS & throughput for different disk types, and how performance scales with disk size. For understanding and monitoring disk performance, you can use `Azure Monitor` and `Azure Storage metrics`, which provide insights into various metrics, including total transactions (which can be a proxy for IOPS when divided by the monitoring interval) and throughput.

Answer (score 0):

The consumed IOPS percentage for a data disk on a VM in Azure is calculated by dividing the actual data disk IOPS completed by the provisioned data disk IOPS. This calculation is the same for both OS and data disks. The formula for consumed IOPS percentage is: (Actual IOPS / Provisioned IOPS) * 100%.
Where
*Actual IOPS is the sum of actual read and write operations per second*
and
*Provisioned IOPS refers to the IOPS limit assigned to the disk*, based on its size and type.

Example-
If your Standard SSD of 128GB is specified to support up to 500 IOPS and you observe 540 reads/sec and 542 writes/sec, your actual IOPS would be (540+542) = 1082

Now if your provisioned IOPS is 500 then,

```
IOPS Consumed Percentage= (Actual IOPS/Provisional IOPS) * 100%
```

So, IOPS Consumed Percentage= (1082/500) * 100%=216.4%

Reference document-

- [Disk performance metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-metrics#storage-io-utilization-metrics)